# How many samples to be reasonably sure?

Tags: probability, sampling, hoeffdings-inequality

I am new to probability, and I am struggling with the right language to ask or google this question.

I have a population of size $n$ and everyone is say some color. I want to verify that at least half the population is red to within some $\epsilon$ accuracy. How many members of the population do I need to query?

I am not sure which of the main theorems of probability to use - chernoff bound, Markov, central limit theorem, etc.

Comment: You don't need any theorems, but it helps to know how to work with the Binomial distribution.  Good keywords include "sample size," "power," "binomial," "experimental design," and "one-sample test of proportions." When $n$ is *very* small (compared to $1/\epsilon^2$) you need a test with a "finite population correction" and the relevant distribution is Hypergeometric rather than Binomial (there are some more keywords for searching ;-).